# Decoding JWT in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, jwt

I have an issue that I'm now completely at a loss over.
I have an authentication server that creates and sends JWT's to a unity application (android/VR).

The auth server creates a token as such

```
        private string GenerateJwtToken(User user)
        {
            var symmetricKey = Convert.FromBase64String(_tokenSettings.Secret);

            var expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(Convert.ToInt32(15));

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.PrimarySid, user.Id.ToString()),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Username),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FirstName),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, user.LastName),
                    new Claim("company", user.Company),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "api_user"),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Expiration, $"{expires.ToShortDateString() + " " + expires.ToShortTimeString()}"),
                }),

                Expires = expires,

                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
                    new SymmetricSecurityKey(symmetricKey),
                    SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
            };

            var securityToken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
            var token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(securityToken);

            return token;
        }
```

I have no issues decoding this and getting out the claims in a console application. This is where the confusion comes in. When I try and perform the same task in Unity and build the application to the VR headset, I'm met with issues, namely this

```
"IDX10729: Unable to decode the header 'header' as Base64Url encoded string. jwtEncodedString: 'Token here'."
```

The unity auth service looks like this

```
        public async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string username, string password)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage())
                {
                    //TODO: Replace this hardcoded URL value here.
                    request.RequestUri = new Uri("{{URL Emmited}}");
                    request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;

                    var body = new AuthRequest()
                    {
                        Username = username,
                        Password = password
                    };

                    var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body), encoding: Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                    request.Content = content;

                    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

                    var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    var tokenContent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(responseContent);

                    var token = tokenContent.Token;

                    return token;
                }
            }
        }
```

and retrieving the claims, I've tried two different ways

```
        public string GetUserName(string token)
        {
            try
            {
                var securityToken = new JwtSecurityToken(token);
                return securityToken?.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == "given_name").Value;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                //log exception here
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
```

and

```
        public string GetUserName(string token)
        {
            try
            {
                var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                var securityToken = handler.ReadJwtToken(token);

                return securityToken?.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == "given_name").Value;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                //log exception here
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
```

ReadJwtToken internally just creates a new JwtSecurityToken object so I assume there's something in that I'm missing.

Both of these throw the same "Unable to decode the header 'header' as Base64Url encoded string" error, however, if I do `handler.CanReadToken(token);` this returns true, which baffles me even more.

Anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening and any clues on how to fix it.

some further information; the token I retrieve can be decoded in JWT.io and in a console app, I'm using the dotnet standard 2.0 assemblies for System.IdentityModel, System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JWT, System.IdentityModel.Tokens, System.IdentityModel.Logging and Newtonsoft.Json